# How to train a custom model for speech to text Cognitive Services?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

We build an Speech To Text Application. In this Conversation always in dutch language. But in some cases English and Dutch words are same. At that time how can i train my model.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do the task

1. Train the model with audio samples of the language Dutch (Belgium or Standard) with related transcript
2. Without any audio file give the text file of the language to train the model
3. By default settings can be applied like train and test sampling separation, check the sample count and divide the sets.

create a training file with few sentences (repeated content also acceptable). Train the model with that file. Based on the language priority, the file has to contain Dutch and English related words.

Use the following can help you to create a [pronunciation file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-and-train?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#guidelines-to-create-a-pronunciation-file)

Comment: Hey @PoornachnadraRaoPillarisetti! Kindly verify the above given solution and acknowledge, so that it can help the Community in reutilize this incase similar questions are posted by other Users.